# Difference between ValidationMessage and ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

For validation purpose I am using validationMessage and ValidationMessageFor Helpers. Both are displaying the error messages , so what is the major difference between validate message and  validation message for. I searched in various web sites but I can't find the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
 @Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", "Main Error", new {style="color:gray;" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName,"",new {@style="color:green;" })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.. except that `ValidationMessageFor` is indeed *strongly typed*... whereas `ValidationMessage` is *stringly typed* (read: weakly typed).

The second one gives you the added benefit of being caught as an error.. before runtime.

You also appear to have different styles on them.. so that is also a difference :)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time I use ValidationMessageFor() passing the expression and allowing MVC to figure out the field name. However, there are times when MVC will not correctly figure out the field name and you need to pass the field name as string using ValidationMessage().

If your model is a complex type with collections (or even nested collections) you need to build the field name yourself.

Example:  ValidationMessage(“Car[0].Wheels[0].Size”)